# Encoding failed during converting and saving video using php-ffmpeg in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, ffmpeg, ffmpeg-php

i'm using https://github.com/PHP-FFMpeg/PHP-FFMpeg package to convert user video uploads to `mp4` format, note that I'm using **Laravel framework** for development process.
But I'm facing error for this and Im not really sure what im doing wrong because all it says is that Encoding is failed. I attached the errors image below you can see that at the bottom.

This is my function which handles user uploads:

```
public function upload()
    {
        $this->putVideoIntoStorage();
        $this->ffmpeg->saveVideo($this->storageManager->getAbsolutePathOf($this->video->getClientOriginalName()));

        return $this->saveVideoIntoDatabase();
    }
```

This is the function which handles saving and converting video to `mp4` using `php-ffmpeg`

```
 public function saveVideo(String $path)
    {

        $ffmpeg = FFMpeg::create([
            'ffmpeg.binaries' => config('services.ffmpeg.ffmpeg_path'),
            'ffprobe.binaries' => config('services.ffmpeg.ffprobe_path'),
            'timeout'          => 3600, // The timeout for the underlying process
            'ffmpeg.threads'   => 12,   // The number of threads that FFMpeg should use
        ]);


        $video = $ffmpeg->open($path);

        $video->save(new X264(), 'video.mp4');
    }
```

This is the error im getting: [Errors Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I7MBJ.png)
I can provide more details if you need just ask me, I would be really glad if someone can help me through this.

Comment: Turn [debug mode](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/errors) on, you should then have access to a stack trace with helpful errors.

Comment: Tip: move long-running processes to a `Job`, which allows you to quickly return a response to the user, and than start processing the code. You may also try to run the above code in a tinker session `php artisan tinker` with an already uploaded file and check for errors.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the proper way to do it:

```
$format = new FFMpeg\Format\Video\X264();
$format->setAudioCodec("libmp3lame");

$video->save($format, '/path/to/new/file');
```